# Same value when random is used

Tags: python, random

I have a same value when I am using this code. What am I doing wrong in the random?

```
data = data[data["VN"] >= 1000]
data_T1 = data[data["TARGET"] == 1]
data_T0 = data[data["TARGET"] == 0]
data_T0_random = data_T0.loc[np.random.choice(data_T0.index, 10000)]
data = data_T1.append(data_T0_random)
print('q:', len(data.index))
rr = data.drop_duplicates()
print('qq:', len(rr.index))
```

Comment: Some more context around the data structures would help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace=False`

**Ex:**

```
data_T0_random=data_T0.loc[np.random.choice(data_T0.index, 10000, replace=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
data_T0_random=data_T0.loc[np.random.choice(data_T0.index, 10000)]
```

to:

```
data_T0_random=random.sample(data_T0,10000)
```

More info:

> random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
>   Return a k sized list of elements chosen from the population with replacement. If the population is empty, raises IndexError.
>
> random.sample(population, k)
>   Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.